# MySQL Query loop HELP without using PHP

Tags: mysql, loops

I have the following query:

```
SET @year1 = 2011;

select  B.YearID, sum(B.ab), sum(B.h), sum(B.h)/ sum(B.ab)
    From Batting B join Pitching P 
    on (P.playerID = B.playerID and B.yearID = P.yearid and B.ab > 0 ) 

        where  B.yearid = @year1
```

This works fine to retrieve results for one year.  But can I do a loop using on mySQL that would allow me to execute the query and see results for each year?

This code does not work and produces syntax errors:

```
SET @year1 = 2011;

While @year1 <= 2014 DO

SET @year1 = @year1 + 1;

select  B.YearID, sum(B.ab), sum(B.h), sum(B.h)/ sum(B.ab)
    From Batting B join Pitching P 
    on (P.playerID = B.playerID and B.yearID = P.yearid and B.ab > 0 ) 

        where  B.yearid = @year1;
End While
```

Can I write a query in MySQL or must I use a language such as PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest it to use group by:

```
select  B.YearID, sum(B.ab), sum(B.h), sum(B.h)/ sum(B.ab)
From Batting B join Pitching P 
on (P.playerID = B.playerID and B.yearID = P.yearid and B.ab > 0 ) 
where b.yearid>=2011 and b.yearid<=2014
group by B.yearid;
```

This will give you the list at once.

A loop would also be possible in a stored procedure however you would have to use a WHILE for syntax reasons:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE someProcedure(IN start_year INT, end_year INT) 
BEGIN
  DECLARE v_year_id INT;
  SET v_year_id=start_year;
  WHILE(v_year_id<end_year)
  LOOP
    select  B.YearID, sum(B.ab), sum(B.h), sum(B.h)/ sum(B.ab)
    From Batting B join Pitching P 
    on (P.playerID = B.playerID and B.yearID = P.yearid and B.ab > 0 ) 
    WHERE yearId=v_year_id;
    group by B.yearid; 
    SET v_year_id=v_year_id+1;
  END WHILE;
END;
```

The local variable v_year_id could also be eliminated but has been added here for clarity. If you eliminate v_year_id it would look like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE someProcedure(IN start_year INT, end_year INT) 
BEGIN
  WHILE(start_year<end_year)
  LOOP
    select  B.YearID, sum(B.ab), sum(B.h), sum(B.h)/ sum(B.ab)
    From Batting B join Pitching P 
    on (P.playerID = B.playerID and B.yearID = P.yearid and B.ab > 0 ) 
    WHERE yearId=start_year;
    group by B.yearid; 
    SET start_year=start_year+1;
  END WHILE;
END;
```

Calling the procedure would be done with:

```
CALL someProcedure(2011,2014);
```

Comment: That does exactly what I need, thank you.  But I'd still like to know if I am able to use some sort of loop?

Comment: Now with loop (p.s. appreciation on stackoverflow is shown by marking the answer as OK with the mark and upvoting the answer).